# REST service for stateless computation

Tags: rest, web-services, restful-architecture

I need to create a method in my REST API that will be used to perform some computation. For sake of simplicity, assume that I need to implement a method that for a given list of objects will return its length.

It should only compute the length and return to the client, so no resource will be modified server side. As it does not modify any resources, one would expect that it should be a `GET` request. However, as the list may be large and the objects may be complex, it looks like I need to make it as a `POST` request. This would however violate the standard that `POST` is used in REST to create resources.

What would be your solution to this problem?

Answer (score 4):

### First solution

According to [RESTful Web Services Cookbook](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596801694.do) you can treat your computation as a resource and just `GET` it. For example:

```
-- Request
GET /computations?param1=2&param2=2 HTTP/1.1

-- Response
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "result": 4
}
```

It sounds good for fast computations with small amount of input parameters. But if your computation isn't that then you can use second solution.

### Second solution

Treat both computation and result as resources. `POST` computation and `GET` result. For example:

First you create a computation

```
-- Request
POST /computations HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "param1": 2,
    "param2": 2
}

-- Response
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Location: /computations/1
```

Then you can get this computation

```
-- Request
GET /computations/1 HTTP/1.1

-- Response
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "param1": 2,
    "param2": 2
}
```

But also you can get a result (`/computations/1/result`) of this computation

```
-- Request
GET /computations/1/result HTTP/1.1

-- Response
HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
Cache-Control: max-age=3600,must-revalidate
```

But oh no! There is no result yet. Server tells us to come back in an hour (`Cache-Control: max-age=3600,must-revalidate`) and try again. The second solution allows you to make computation asynchronous (in case when it takes a lot of time) or you can compute it once, store the result in some DB and serve it quickly when requested for the next time.

```
-- Request
GET /computations/1/result HTTP/1.1

-- Response
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "result": 4
}
```

Comment: Looks OK, except you are not passing the ID in the POST payload => the server will auto assign and ID but how do you know what it is? It needs to be returned in the response payload ... at the very least. Imagine the ID is a hash, e.g. a12b43c98a and you don't get it back in the response body after it the computation resources is created :)

Comment: Thank you for posting these solutions. Upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Pragmatic answer: use `POST`.

Weasely answer: use `POST`. Your request contains a resource (or set of resources) that you want the server to *temporarily* create (the list of objects). If the server *happens* to delete that resource immediately after the `POST` has been successfully dealt with, what of it?

Comment: What would the the response of this `POST` request? How will it contain the result of the computation?

Comment: Hm, that is not very consistent with REST principles. What you are suggesting is doing POST and DELETE with just POST :)

Answer (score 1):

The moral of the story here is that with REST you **always** assume a resource, even if in reality one is **not** needed and likely **not** created. In the examples above, what if I want to store neither the computation resource (a JSON object that consists of parameters and some sort of operation) nor the computation result resource? I cannot. I can either

1. Treat this as a fake resource with GET (pretend that it exists) or
2. Create two resources with a single POST - one for the computation and one for its result - and then use the corresponding GET to retrieve either of those.

A sneaky assumption here also is that there is NO POST for /computation/<computaiton_id>/result because results are only created via computations.